# Help using Simple Vector Library (SVL) with Xcode

Tags: xcode, macos, opengl, sdl

I am writing a small program using openGl and SDL.  I need to use SVL for various reasons but I cannot get it to link up properly in Xcode.  Has anyone done this before and could talk me through it? I followed the readme from SVL and get the following when I run make install:

ip-156-133:svl-1.5 2 Tom$ sudo make install

installing into /usr/local/include/svl /usr/local/doc

done.

installing into /usr/local/lib /usr/local/include

chmod: lib/*: No such file or directory

make: [install-libs] Error 1 (ignored)

cp: lib/*: No such file or directory

make: [install-libs] Error 1 (ignored)

done.

Could be this be part of the problem?

Also I'm not sure where to add the -lsvl flag and -lsvl.dbg etc.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: What is "SVL"?  [This?](http://www.cs.cmu.edu/~ajw/doc/svl.html).  Edit your question to clarify.

Answer (score 0):

[SVL](http://www.cs.cmu.edu/~ajw/doc/svl.html) seems rather unmaintained, given that the latest version is nearly eight years old.

I'd recommend [Eigen](http://eigen.tuxfamily.org/index.php?title=Main_Page), which is under active development and has the added benefit of being a [header-only library](http://eigen.tuxfamily.org/index.php?title=Main_Page#Requirements).